# The puzzling eigenvalues of a differential equation system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I have a question here, in order to have a stable solution of a differential equation, is that right we should have all eigenvalues less one?

But I have seen a incomprehensible situation in **difference equation**, for instance

\begin{align*}
x_{t+1}&=a x_{t} -b y_t\\
 y_t&= y_{t+1}-cx_{t+1}
  \end{align*}
$a$, $b$ and $c$ are parameters, there are two eignenvalues, one has to be less than one, the other has to be larger than one in order to keep system stable. I completely do not grasp this idea. If anyone knows, please explain to me! Thanks!

Comment: Notice this difference between difference and differential equations: $x_{n+1}=ax_n$ has solutions involving $a^n$, while $x'=ax$ has solutions involving $e^{at}$. For $a^n$, the big difference is between $a\gt1$ and $a\lt1$; for $e^{at}$, the big difference is between $a\gt0$ and $a\lt0$.

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite the equations into the form
\begin{align*}
x_{t+1}&=a x_{t} -b y_t\\
 y_{t+1}-cx_{t+1}&=y_t.
\end{align*}
This has the form $A\bar x_{t+1}=C\bar x_t$. Now, $A$ is not singular and so one has $\bar x_{t+1}=A^{-1}C\bar x_t$. Now put
$$
\bar x_t=\lambda^t\left(\begin{array}{c}
 x_1 \\ x_2\end{array}\right)=\lambda^t\bar x_0
$$
and you are left with the eigenvalue problem after substitution

$$\lambda\bar x_0=A^{-1}C\bar x_0.$$

As stated in the comment area you should consider the case of the eigenvalues being $\lambda>1$ and $\lambda<1$.